# php not writing content to text file

Tags: php, forms, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to write content from a form to a text file, and don't know why it is not working.  I have uploaded the code on a free host like 000webhost and everything works fine. So not sure if there is some misconfiguration to my CentOS server which is CentOS release 6.5 (Final). Or if there is something wrong with the code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)
{
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting, then possibly check the file permissions. Oh and instructing the browser to redirect might prematurely severe the connection and thus the PHP process.

Comment: the first line will transfer the control to example.com , do you have the file data.txt located on example.com or on your server?

Comment: I have the file data.txt on the centos server, I have also tried setting the permissions to 777 for data.txt, as I stated it works on the free host but not my server, it should basically write to the file then redirect. which works fine on the freehost.

Comment: the file will be empty because the page will be redirected to example.com , the remain code is never executed

Comment: When you do get it working you may find it to be more efficient to save the entire output to a temporary php variable and write the whole thing in one go instead of 5 calls to `fwrite()`.

Comment: I have removed the redirect, but same outcome.. it wont write to the file data.txt file. On the freehost it redirects and writes to the file just fine. the way I pasted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct permissions to the folder you're trying to write to.  It's probably getting by the apache user (www-data) or equiv.

Also, PHP has some nicer methods of writing to files.  Try something like:

```
$output = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    $output .= sprintf("%s = %s\n", $key, $val);

file_put_contents('data.txt', $output);
```

That should be clear as long as `$_POST` isn't 2D.  If it's 2D, or more for debugging purposes, why not use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) (as it's recursive), eg.

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', print_r($_POST, true));
```

The second argument makes it return a string rather than actually print.

For clarity, I'd consider putting the `header('Location: xxx')` call at the end (even though it won't make a functional difference).